# where to find intel parallel studio's command line in win10?

Tags: intel-fortran, intel-parallel-studio

After installed the parallel studio xe 2015 cluster, I want to build the fortran from the command line (rather than through visual studio). The release notes show me the way like
[image]

However, in the start up menu , I would not find neither. Then where can I find the intel 64 command like and build the intel fortran complier? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if none of the compilers or tools got installed. It could be that the required Visual Studio was not installed (a Fortran-only Visual Studio environment is installed for commercial and academic licenses.)  Please ask in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/ and provide more details of your environment and what you have installed. It would be especially useful for you to rerun the Parallel Studio XE installer and take screenshots of any messages it displays.